# iOS: Make sure phone is portrait, and perpendicular to floor

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Forgive me if this is newb question, but I am new to this part of iOS programming and I'm a bit confused.

I am working on a demo that requires the iPhone to be held in portrait mode, and (as close to) perpendicular to the floor.

Simply making sure the phone is locked in portrait mode is not enough as I am doing image processing with the rear camera, and I need to make sure the image is captured with the phone held upright.

(i.e. screen may be portrait, but user could still be holding the phone sideways)

What's the best way to address this?

I understand that the on-board IMU will allow me to determine where the ground is (i.e. gravity), but how do I address rotation around a specific axis?

Comment: The [Core Motion framework](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coremotion) will allow you to determine the attitude of the device.